# How to get the data from Subscribers message with python

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
In my program, I try to get the Pose msg data which publish from other topic.

But when I print the variable which to read the Subscribers message, I will get the all values are 0.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import rospy 
import geometry_msgs.msg 
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose 

grasp_goal = Pose()

def callback(msg):
    global grasp_goal
    grasp_goal = msg.grasp_goal

# Create a ROS node.
rospy.init_node('move_to_grasp', anonymous=True)
rospy.loginfo('Start to grasp the object...')

# Subscribe to the ROS topic that contains the grasp data.
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/grasp_pose', Pose, callback)

rospy.loginfo("x:%f y:%f z:%f w:%f x:%f y:%f z:%f", grasp_goal.position.x, grasp_goal.position.y, grasp_goal.position.z, grasp_goal.orientation.w, grasp_goal.orientation.x, grasp_goal.orientation.y, grasp_goal.orientation.z)
```

This is echo /grasp_pose topic:
[image: image description]

This is result, all value are zero:
[image: image description]

Thanks for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323608/how-to-get-the-data-from-subscribers-message-with-python/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-05-21**:
Please don't use images to display text. Images are not searchable and the text cannot be copied and pasted. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the text instead of using images. See the [support page](https://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do)

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-05-21**:
sorry for mistake, I will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your program is not waiting for a message to be received before it is printing out the pose information from the global variable. In order what your program is doing.

1. intializes global variables
   2, setup node
   3, register subscriber (not the same as waiting for a message)
   4, print values of global variables
   5, shutdown

If you try printing out the values of the global pose variable in a 1 second loop, then you will see the correct values from messages being printed after the first message has been received. It might be a good idea to put a print in your callback, to confirm messages are being received too.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-05-21**:
Sorry, I'm still not sure what do you mean. Could you provide me some example code like this?
It can help me know it clearly.